# Can I tell a browser to start display of a web page already scrolled down?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a web page with a fixed-size layout, it's fine in its current implementation even if it's far from "state of art", but a little too high for a mobile device screen.

Since the "header" part doesn't really matter to anyone, everyone wants to immediately pan / scroll down a little when viewing the page on a mobile device (or, broadly speaking, on a viewport shorter than the page fixed height).

Is there some HTML or JS magic I can do to tell the browser to start displaying the page already-scrolled-down X pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you could try [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/). You'll need to work out where on the page your target is, though...

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like links and anchors.

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/main.html#bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchors is one solution, but the way I find really nice is to use http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/LocalScroll. So use can detect User Agent in Javascript and scroll down in proper place using this plugin.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure anchors would work if you are trying to implement this on the homepage.
If the header is completely pointless in mobile browser this you could use html to detect that a mobile browser is being used then from this load CSS with the header hidden, or load it at the bottom perhaps. If this sounds like a viable option I can post examples.